# Hashing passwords using SHA512 when UPDATE-ing

Tags: php, mysql, hash, edit

I successfully hashed my passwords for the new accounts i created, however, when i log in using the previous non-hashed passwords, i can't log in. but i can log in when i use the hashed passwords. so how do i update the previous passwords to be hashed?

Here is the update php file.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");
        if (!$dbcheck) {
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    $userid = $_GET['user_id'];
    $hashed = hash('sha512', $password);     // where should i use this? or what should i do with it?
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET
    first_name = '$_POST[first_name]',
    middle_name = '$_POST[middle_name]',
    last_name = '$_POST[last_name]',
    gender =    '$_POST[gender]',
    email = '$_POST[email]',
    password =  '$_POST[password]',
    birth_date =    '$_POST[birth_date]',
    company =   '$_POST[company]',
    company_address =   '$_POST[company_address]',
    home_address = '$_POST[home_address]',
postal_code =   '$_POST[postal_code]',
city =  '$_POST[city]',
province =  '$_POST[province]',
home_phone =    '$_POST[home_phone]',
mobile_phone =  '$_POST[mobile_phone]' WHERE id=$userid";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }
header('refresh: 0;url=userdb.php');
$message = "User Successfully Updated";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

Comment: If you have an already large user base, best thing to do is to send them each an Email with a password reset method. That's what I'd do. I'm sure it's possible though, I have seen something to that effect some time back, but you'd probably spend more time doing the conversion then just a simple password reset for people to do and inform them of a better and safer method implemented; they'll appreciate it ;)

Comment: And another user still using deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: In addition, if you plan or consider doing it the way I suggested, it's just going to require a simple `UPDATE table SET pass='$hash' WHERE user='$user'`

Comment: I spy [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Everything about this is **wrong**. Ignoring errors with `@`. [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Using the obsolete and dangerous `mysql_query` interface. Total disregard for proper password hashing practices. Irritating modal JavaScript alerts. If this is on the public internet, you're living on borrowed time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hashed = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);
```

then in your query use $hashed :

```
$sql = "...
password =  '$hashed',
...";
```

Comment: This could probably work, but what if the OP decides to go with `password_hash()` later on?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah well, what if OP decides to use PDO later on ? What if he decides to use `$_GET()` later on ? I'm just pointing out its error. By the way, I could suggest OP to use `password_hash()` instead of `hash`. Or maybe I didn't get your point ?

Comment: The API here is irrelevant (SQL is SQL, any which way you slice it); it's the way the password is stored (and retrieved) in DB. OP can use any API he/she wants.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes sure and I agree with your first comment on question. I'm just giving a very direct answer to OP's problem.

Comment: Merci Clément ;) bonne journée.